Disprove an altered limit convergence statement.
I found this exercise in a textbook I'm working through:
Disprove the following by means of a counterexample:
($\forall x$ s.t. $0<|x-a|<\delta, |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$) implies ($\forall x$ s.t. $0<|x-a|<\delta /2, |f(x)-L|<\epsilon/2$).
I have a feeling it's implying that the statement should include a "$\forall \epsilon>0 ,\exists \delta$ s.t", but it hasn't been included in the book. However, if I add that in, I'm finding it incredibly difficult to disprove!
Many thanks in advance.

Let's say you pick your function $f$ and consider its limit $L$ at $a$. For a specific $\varepsilon>0$, let's say you find a specific $\delta>0$ such that whenever $x$ is $\delta$ close to $a$, $f(x)$ is $\varepsilon$ close to $L$. It's asking you to find a counterexample to disprove that this implies that whenever $x$ is within $\frac{\delta}{2}$ of $a$, $f(x)$ is within $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ of $L$. Hint: think about exponential functions.

Ah, thank you. The textbook I'm using hadn't mentioned anything to do with exponential functions yet, so I assumed the use of them was forbidden or something, so I didn't try.
